Google Gemini Pro not providing response if tools are given
Google Gemini Pro works well if not tools are provided
For example:
import google.generativeai as genai


def multiply(a:float, b:float):
    """returns a * b."""
    return a*b

model = genai.GenerativeModel(model_name='gemini-1.0-pro')

chat = model.start_chat()
response = chat.send_message('who is the president of usa')
response.text

Output: 'Joe Biden'
But when i integrate tools in it and query something else than tool, the model not works well.
import google.generativeai as genai


def multiply(a:float, b:float):
    """returns a * b."""
    return a*b

model = genai.GenerativeModel(model_name='gemini-1.0-pro',
                              tools=[multiply])

chat = model.start_chat(enable_automatic_function_calling=True)
response = chat.send_message('who is the president of usa')
response.text

Output: 'I cannot fulfill this request. The available tools lack the desired functionality.'
or 'This question cannot be answered from the given source.'
Can someone please help me to resolve this problem

I have the exact same problem. Did you find any workaround? :(

@prithul Ugh, this is proving to be a real head-scratcher. I've been combing through the documentation and forums all day, but no dice so far. Hopefully, a solution will emerge soon.

you need to use the function invoking feature in a chat environement allowing following argument to true
enable_automatic_function_calling=True

like
 model = genai.GenerativeModel( model_name='gemini-pro', tools = [function] )
 chat = model.start_chat(enable_automatic_function_calling=True)
 response = chat.send_message(content)

this will 100% work


The question includes your recommended line of code. 2) Please remove wording such as this will 100% work.


@Durgesh I've already implemented that functionality.
